# limit problem correct approach?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I'm trying to find limit as $n \to \infty$ of

$\Big(\frac{n^{4}11^{n}+n^{9}9^{n}}{7^{2n}+1}\Big)$

I'm trying to apply that $\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}$ can be rewritten using the ratio rule as, $x\Big(\frac{n}{n+1}\Big)^{k} \to x$ where $x > 1$ and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

I've gotten up to $\Big(\frac{n^{4}11^{n}+n^{9}9^{n}}{7^{2n}+1}\Big) = \frac{n^{4}(11^{n}+n^{5}9^{n})}{7^{2n}+1}$.

I'm not sure what to do next, or if this is the best strategy for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Well you can use the result that $n^kx^n\to 0 $ if $|x|<1$. To use this result divide numerator and denominator by $49^n$ and conclude the desired limit as $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\left(\frac{n^{4}11^{n}+n^{9}9^{n}}{7^{2n}+1}\right)=\frac{n^411^n}{7^{2n}}\left(\frac{1+\frac{n^{5}9^{n}}{11^n}}{1+\frac1{7^{2n}}}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{n^411^n}{7^{2n}}=\frac{n^411^n}{49^{n}}\le\frac{n^4}{2^{n}}\frac{11^n}{20^{n}}$$

Comment: hi, So then we have that $\frac{n^{4}}{2^{n}} \to \frac{1}{2}$ and that $\frac{11^{n}}{20^{n}} \to 0$ therefore the whole expression goes to $0$.

Comment: Why should $n^4/2^n \to 1/2$?

Comment: I tried using the $\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}$ result with $x=2$ and $k=4$ but taking the reciprocal of it.

Comment: Then $\frac{n^{4}}{2^{n}} \to \frac{1}{2}\to 0$, am I wrong?

Comment: I understand, but at the same time I don't. I thought that the result I used meant that it will converge to what we call $x$. But at the same time I see how you get the above result.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner $2^n$ becomes huge and huge with respect to $n^4$ or $n^{1000}$ therefore the limit is $0$. Ratio test is a good way to prove that. Maybe you should study or revise in detail the proof for the ratio test to convince yourself.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner For $\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}$, the limit of the ratio converges to $x$ and when $x>1$ by ratio test theorem assures that $\frac{x^{n}}{n^{k}}\to \infty$.

Comment: @AnalysisLearner Take a look here for [Ratio Test for Sequence Convergence](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-ratio-test-for-sequence-convergence).

Comment: thanks for the help. I was forgetting that it tends to infinity, it makes sense now. Thanks.